# ConTeXt - How to replicate this LaTeX tcolourbox title box placement with frame?

Tags: context, tcolorbox, frame-title

Desired effect:

[image]

Just to clarify - this is LATEX code, asking for a replication with CONTEXT code.
Did you understand that?
Please leave comments if you didn't get that.

MWE (LaTeX):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\huge\scshape,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{mybox}{Goals}
\\
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Question is how to replicate this LaTeX/tcolorbox code in ConTeXt.

Comment: Is that clear enough? :)

Comment: I was only trying to help... If you think it is necessary to put "Did you understand that?" this is your choice. IMHO it would have been sufficient to add a sentence like "I would like to reproduce this output with ConTeXt." at the end.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.